# Parsing WXS project file in Groovy/Java

Tags: xml, groovy, wix

I'm trying to parse out project version info in my Groovy-based build script from a 3-party `.wxs` project file having the version defined as `WIX` macro:

```
<?define ProductVersion = '5.0.00' ?>
...
<Product Name="My Product" Version='$(var.ProductVersion)' .... >
...
```

and obviously, such a trick as:

```
def productVersion =  new XmlSlurper().parse(wxsFile).Product.first().attributes().Version
```

would just return `$(var.ProductVersion)`.

Any idea if there are Groovy/Java parsers that could pre-process the WIX XML code to expand the macros?
Or, maybe, there is a way to traverse through the `<?define>` sections (as a workaround, this would do)?

Answer (score 0):

I can't speak for Groovy/Java but in C# Linq to XML world I'd get descendant nodes that are XProcessingInstruction and look for one that matched on ProductVersion.

But in WiX, a preprocessor variable can also be passed into the build or factored out into other sources.  For example, in Team Foundation Server builds TFS sets an environment variable called TF_BUILD_NUMBER.  In my MSBuild (.wixproj)  I do a RegEx Match on this and assign it to an msbuild property.  Then I assign the property to a preprocessor variable and finally I use the variable in the Product element as you saw.

So I guess I'm wondering what you are actually trying to do before I can give you more specific guidance.   How you would then implement that in Groovy / Java is outside of my experience.  I'd sure it would be similar to what we do in C#.

Comment: Alas, C# isn't an option for me at all, as I need this for Ant+Groovy build script that would run on Unix, and there's a partner's MSI project that carries misc version info I need...  
But thanks anyway :)

Comment: I was trying to explain in abstract concepts what you needed to know. I never suggested that you do it in C#.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete solution, but should you provide a hint in case you'll find no better solution.

**parse the declarations**

```
 import groovy.util.Eval 
 def  var = [:]

 // <?define ProductVersion = '5.0.00' ?>
 // for each define transform to this assignment ...
 var.ProductVersion  = '5.0.00'
```

**parse attribute**

parse as usual, but replace to curly parentheses and set the varible name to **x**

```
 def wxsFile = '<Product Name="My Product" Version="$(var.ProductVersion)" />'  
 def productVersion =  new XmlSlurper().parseText(wxsFile).first().attributes().Version.replaceAll(/\(var\./, "{x.").replaceAll(/\)/, "}")
```

this gives a string *${x.ProductVersion}*

**evaluate**

Using the *Eval.x* you can pass the daclaration variables (defined in the *var* hashmap) and evaluate strings referencing those variables. The varible name *x* is hardcoded, this is the reason for renaming it.

```
 def expr =  "return \"${productVersion}\""
 println expr
 //  return "${x.ProductVersion}"

 println Eval.x(var, expr)
 //  5.0.00
```